# Is it possible to create Code first approach in Visual studio 2013 Ultimate version?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, 3-tier

Is it possible to create code first approach in Visual Studio 2013 ultimate version? I am using visual studio 2013, .Net frame work 4.5, sql server 2008, and Entity Frame work version -6.0.0.

I'm not able to create Code first approach. If I go and right click  on the project name `->Add->NewItem->Ado.net->` in that, I can't find Code first approach.

[image]

I don't know what the main issue is. If anyone could help me to clear this problem I'd appreciate it. Then I have another doubt too... I would like to create my MVC project in 3-tier architecture using Business access layer and also database access layer. I create my MVC application in  2-tier . Now I would like to create in 3-tier. Please suggest some links to create this MVC application in 3-tier architecture.

Anyone give me suggestions for these two things.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need the EF Power Tools: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Comment: Nothing necessarily wrong with 2-tier, but if you are running into issues there are plenty of examples out there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-20.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: i have to add EF power tools in my application to create Code First approach steve greence?

Comment: Power Tools allow you to reverse engineer an existing database. Otherwise the normal code first flow is to create your classes and let EF build the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download EF tooling for VS 2013 because it was shipped out of band. You can get it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

Comment: i have to install this EF tool  in my system  to create code first approach Pawel?

Comment: You need to install this and then you will two more options in the wizard to use code first.